# the rows of a jtable does not accept the selection

Tags: java, swing, colors, selection, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable. I've used  setDefaultRenderer to colour some rows like this:

```
Acueill.jTableProduit.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
                super.getTableCellRendererComponent( table, value, false, hasFocus, row, col);
                final int qte = (int) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 7);
                final int min = (int) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 8);
                if (qte < min) {
                    setBackground(Color.red);
                } else {
                    setBackground(table.getBackground());
                }
                return this;
            }
        });
```

But my jtable doesn’t accept the selection rows. How can fix this?

Comment: Instead of checking to see if the row was selected or not, you just changed the background color to what ever you wanted

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are trying to use a single renderer for your table even though you have String and numeric data in different columns. This is not a good idea. Typically numbers are formatted and displayed differently than String. So you would need to create multiple renderers for each data type in the table.

For a different approach, check out [Table Row Renderering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) which shows how you can set the background of an entire row without a custom renderer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the selected rows keep the selection color, try this:

```
...
if (!isSelected && qte < min) {
    setBackground(Color.red);
}
...
```

Comment: And if it's selected you'll...set the color to the tables background color?